# Extract a Range Value and assign to a String Variable

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010, vba

I would like to extract a range value and assign it to a string variable.

In the following image, the value that I would like to store to a string variable is from `Range("E10:J11").Value(1,1)` which holds the string "Disputes/Appeals".

[Range values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT5Hd.png)

The codes that I used for implementation are:

```
Dim P3 As String

'This line gives me Run-time error '13'
'Type mismatch
P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Value
```

Having this error, I knew that I need to be specific to the arguments of `.Value` so that my assignments would agree to the same data type.

Based from the image, following the `Range("E10:J11").Value(1,1)` specification, here is what I did:

```
'This line gives me Run-Time error '450'
'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Value(1, 1)
```

Now I think I am on the right track but I could just not find out the correct syntax or the proper arguments for this type of assignment.

Comment: `P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Cells(1).Value`

Comment: Hi @Tim, This solution works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put the `(1,1)` in front of the `.Value`:

```
P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11")(1, 1).Value
```

Comment: This solution works too @Scott. I would have never thought to put the `(1,1)` before `.Value`. Thank you. I just wonder why I could not find any examples of these two solutions, my intentions of assigning a string value from a range to a variable string seems to be a general thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Value` returns a `Variant` (which is basically a "container" type that can hold pretty much anything).  If there is only one cell in the `Range`, it will contain the underlying contents of the cell. If there is more than one cell in the `Range`, it returns a 2 dimensional array of `Variant`, with each element containing the underlying contents of one cell.  It can also return a `Variant` of type `vbEmpty` or `vbError` if the cell doesn't contain anything or has a formula that results in an error.

When you access this `.Value`...

```
Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Value
```

...you get a 2D array.  That is the reason why your screenshot is showing array indexes.

The reason why *this* code...

```
P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Value(1, 1)
```

...doesn't work, is that `.Value` is actually an *indexed property* with an optional `RangeValueDataType` parameter.  So the compiler interprets the `(1, 1)` the index.  Since you're passing 2 "parameters", you get the "Wrong number of arguments" error.

Although the other answers show different ways of getting the value of the target cell, in order to apply indexing to the return value of `.Value` using property return/array index syntax, you need to explicitly provide an empty parameter list to `.Value`:

```
P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Value()(1, 1)
                                                      '^^
```

Note, this syntax...

```
P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11")(1, 1).Value
```

...provides the index to the Range parameter instead, which returns a one cell `Range`, which has the `.Value` called on *it*.

Comment: Thank for for answering and going even further to explain how `Range.Value` works, greatly appreciated. I did combine all the cells in the range that I selected so in the end it is a single celled range, but I will remember your lesson about how a Range could also contain a 2 dimensional array.

`P3 = Worksheets("NameofmySheet").Range("E10:J11").Value()(1, 1)` works perfectly aswell.